# Almacenar resultado de javascript en una variable php

Tags: php, javascript, hash

Existe alguna manera  de hacer funcionar este código :

```
<script>
function getBaseURL() {
// obtenemos el hash
var jash = window.location.hash;
// lo imprimimos
return jash;
}
</script>

<?php
 $url1 = "<script>getBaseURL();</script>";
 $url = $url1
 echo $url ;
?>
```

Aclaro  lo uso para obtener la url actual que contiene algo como esto

`http://localhost/prueva.php?#access_token=EAALhZB1GcFMUBAIk7fEyHjQUT6wb0N`

El problema es el signo `#` usando `window.location.hash` de `javascript` obtengo lo que busco pero no puedo pasarlo a php

Busco la manera  de guardar el resultado de la variable **jash** de javascript. En la variable **$url** de PHP.

Espero alguna ayuda gracias

Comment: y por que no mejor rescatas el hash desde php?

Comment: El problema es el signo del  #, nunca se enviarán al servidor por que por lo regular se utiliza para anclas de la página del lado del cliente e intentado  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] y no funciona me pregunto conoces otra forma

Comment: No sé lo que quieres hacer pero la única solición para ver a dónde está yendo el usuario es hacer una llamada ajax para obtener ese valor. ¿Para qué necesitas obtenerlo? Quizá podamos ayudarte de otro modo.

Comment: E script utiliza  window.location.hash; para obtener la url actual . que por ejemplo es alago parecido a esto **http://localhost/prueva.php?#access_token=EAALhZB1GcFMUBAIk7fEyHjQUT6wb0N**

Comment: La respuesta de ffflabs es la correcta. Tú supones que el PHP se está ejecutando al tiempo que el JS y eso no es así. PHP se interpreta en el servidor, serializa un HTML de salida y lo entrega vía HTTP a tu navegador, que lo procesa y ejecuta el JavaScript que contiene y ahí se corre tu `<script>`... pero ahí ya no hay PHP a ejecutar. Si no entiendes esa secuencia, vas a seguir pidiendo cosas que no son. Explica cuál es el problema real (qué intentas que pase en el script PHP, en el navegador del usuario, etc) para que recibas una solución que haga eso.

Comment: conoces la forma de enviar datos del navegador/html/javascript al servidor php???

Answer (score 3):

Lo que intentas no se puede hacer. PHP primero procesa todo el texto que le pasaste para generar un HTML.

Cuando haces

```
$url1 = "<script>getBaseURL();</script>";
```

El valor de $url1 es exactamente ese string. En ningún caso el resultado de la evaluación de javascript.

Tal como te sugirieron en otra respuesta, un workaround sería evaluar si el hash existe y redirigir a otra url en donde el valor del hash se presente como parte del query string.

```
<script>
function getBaseURL() {

    var hash = window.location.hash;

    if(hash) {
        window.location.href=window.location.href.split('#')[0]+'?hash='+hash.replace('#','');
    }

}
getBaseURL();
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['hash'])) {
    echo 'hash is :' . $_GET['hash'];
}
```

Pero esto es sólo un workaround. ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente con ese hash? ¿Iniciar sesión del lado del servidor? ¿Hacer algo en el front para validar que esa sesión existe? ¿Modificar el comportamiento del front acorde al hash?

Si lo que quieres hacer es esto último, debieras asumir que PHP te entregará simplemente HTML plano y que el resto de la lógica de negocios (en su primera capa) ocurrirá en el front.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta lo que busco es almacenar el token que devuelve la pagina aclaro que la pagina no es mia y solo pretendo obtener el token que viene en la url para almacenarlo en un txt

Answer (score 1):

Intentalo asi es un ejemplo sencillo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function javascript_to_php() {
        var jsVar1 = "Hello";
        var jsVar2 = "World";
        window.location.href = window.location.href + "?w1=" + jsVar1 + 
        "&w2=" + 
        jsVar2;
    }
</script>

 <?php
  // comprobar si tenemos los parametros w1 y w2 en la URL
  if (isset($_GET["w1"]) && isset($_GET["w2"])) {
     // asignar w1 y w2 a dos variables
     $phpVar1 = $_GET["w1"];
     $phpVar2 = $_GET["w2"];

  // mostrar $phpVar1 y $phpVar2
     echo "<p>Parameters: " . $phpVar1 . " " . $phpVar1 . "</p>";
  } else {
     echo "<p>No parameters</p>";
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Hola Oscar, gracias por aportar. Puedes explicar por qué su codigo no funcionaba y como el tuyo da la solucion? Mira [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tu respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta igual ya lo intentado con el método Get de php pero no es lo que busco ya que window.location.hash; me funciona bien pero aun no puedo darle el valor a una variable de php

Comment: el quiere pasar variables de javacript a php el ejemplo que doy es usando GET

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte.

Puede probar rescatando la variable de la url localhost/?var=1#hash

`<?php 
echo parse_url("http://localhost/?var=1#hash",PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
?>`

El resultado será: hash

Será lo que necesitas?

Comment: el código funciona el único problema es que la url  es aleatoria y no logra capturarla usando php solo usando javascript

Answer (score -1):

> El problema es el signo # usando window.location.hash de javascript
> obtengo lo que busco pero no puedo pasarlo a php
>
> Busco la manera de guardar el resultado de la variable jash de
> javascript. En la variable $url de PHP.

Si el problema son los caracteres raros, prueba a codificarla en Javascript antes de mandarla a PHP, y luego, cuando la reciba PHP, la decodificas.

Javascript:

```
    var jash = 'http://localhost/prueva.php?#access_token=EAALhZB1GcFMUBAIk7fEyHjQUT6wb0N';

    var jashEncoded = encodeURIComponent(jash); 
//http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fprueva.php%3F%23access_token%3DEAALhZB1GcFMUBAIk7fEyHjQUT6wb0N
```

PHP:

```
$urlRecibida = 'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fprueva.php%3F%23access_token%3DEAALhZB1GcFMUBAIk7fEyHjQUT6wb0N'

$urlDecodificada=rawurldecode($urlRecibida)
//http://localhost/prueva.php?#access_token=EAALhZB1GcFMUBAIk7fEyHjQUT6wb0N
```